# Функция должна вывести в длины вложенных массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, циклы

При нажатии b-14 выполняете функцию f14. Функция должна вывести в out-14 длины вложенных в a14 массивов. Через пробел.

```js
let a14 = [
    [],
    [1,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
    [3,4,5,6,7,8],
    [1,2]
];

function f14() {
   let out = '';
document.querySelector('.out-14').innerHTML = out;
}

document.querySelector('.b-14').onclick = f14;
```

```html
<section>
            <p><b>Task 14.</b></p>
            <p>При нажатии b-14 выполняете функцию f14. Функция должна вывести в out-14 длины вложенных в a14 массивов. Через пробел.</p>
            <button class="button-primary b-14">Task-14</button>
            <div class="out-14"></div>
        </section>
```

Comment: `let out = a14.map(a=>a.length).join(' ');`

Answer (score 0):

```
let a14 = [
    [],
    [1,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
    [3,4,5,6,7,8],
    [1,2]
];

function f14() {
   let out = '';
for(let i = 0; i < a14.length; i++){
out += a14[i].length + ' ';
}
document.querySelector('.out-14').innerHTML = out;
}

document.querySelector('.b-14').onclick = f14;

<section>
        <p><b>Task 14.</b></p>
        <p>При нажатии b-14 выполняете функцию f14. Функция должна вывести в out-14 длины вложенных в a14 массивов. Через пробел.</p>
        <button class="button-primary b-14">Task-14</button>
        <div class="out-14"></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

> Функция должна вывести в out-14 длины вложенных в a14 массивов. Через пробел.

Преобразовать массив, использую метод `map()`. https://doka.guide/js/array-map/

Потом превратим массив в строку с разделителем, используя метод `join()` https://basicweb.ru/javascript/js_array_join.php

```js
let a14 = [
  [],
  [1, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [1, 2]
];

function f14() {
  let out = a14.map(a => a.length);
  out = out.join(' ')
  document.querySelector('.out-14').innerHTML = out;
}

document.querySelector('.b-14').addEventListener('click', f14);
```

```html
<section>
  <p><b>Task 14.</b></p>
  <p>При нажатии b-14 выполняете функцию f14. Функция должна вывести в out-14 длины вложенных в a14 массивов. Через пробел.</p>
  <button class="button-primary b-14">Task-14</button>
  <div class="out-14"></div>
</section>
```